# Multiple applications on one server in Flask

Tags: python, flask

Currently my server structure looks like this:

```
/srv/http/:
  index.html
  projects/:
    app1/
    app2/
    appetc/
```

The `index.html` was a Flask application, but I changed it to be a static webpage, since that fit my needs.

What I want is to have my multiple applications (in the `project` folder) be found at the urls they are located at in the file structure. i.e.

```
app1: http://example.com/app1
app2: http://example.com/app2
appetc: http://example.com/appetc
```

Currently this doesn't work. I can navigate to the home page of the apps at the proper url, but if I click on any link (since it's a Flask app) it acts like it's running on the root of the server.

I *do* have root access to the server and am able to edit apache configuration files, but I *do not* have the ability to create more subdomains (my dns provider limits me, and I am currently at that limit). Additionally, I am not set on this layout. I am currently in a transition phase where I can restructure my applications however I want.

Comment: Maybe run a WSGI server (like twisted) and let it spit out different WSGI objects based on the path.

Comment: I currently have WSGI with apache. Is that similar?

Comment: Is this a problem with the hyperlinks on each page not pointing to the correct URL?

Comment: You probably need to set the `WSGIScriptAlias` properly. Ex: `WSGIScriptAlias /app1 /some/path/to/app1.wsgi`

Comment: @MiloGertjejansen Apache (mod_wsgi) spawns a new process for every request. This is not the case in a proxy scenario. I prefer using Apache/Nginx as a proxy to the actual WSGI applications. Question of preference, I guess.

Comment: @cpb2 mod_wsgi is configurable to use a daemon process with the `WSGIDaemonProcess` directive. This allows you to have a long running process instead of spinning one up for every request.

Comment: @erjiang Yes, this is. I think Sean answered it below though. I haven't tested it yet, but it looks like what I was looking for. In any case, what were you thinking?

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/patterns/appdispatch/) provides strategies for running multiple Flask applications, like this using middleware from werkzeug:

```
from werkzeug.wsgi import DispatcherMiddleware
from frontend_app import application as frontend
from backend_app import application as backend

application = DispatcherMiddleware(frontend, {
    '/backend':     backend
})
```